# ExecutorCompletionService wait for n seconds max for completion

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, java-threads

I am using ExecutorCompletionService to submit few tasks. I want to then wait for max, say 5 seconds, and then stop processing.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);     
CompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(
            executorService);
List<Callable<String>> callables = createCallables(); //each callable sleeps randomly between 1-10 seconds and then prints the thread name
for (Callable<String> callable : callables) 
    taskCompletionService.submit(callable);
for (int i = 0; i < callables.size(); i++) {
    Future<String> result = completionService.take();   
    System.out.println(result.get()); 
}
```

Now I don't want to wait for more than 5 seconds for all the tasks to be completed. I just want to collect results of tasks that are done within 5 seconds. How can I achieve that?

```
executorService.shutdown();
executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I have used `shutdown` and `awaitTermination` on `executorService`, but my main thread still waits for all submitted tasks to complete and it takes 10 seconds for all the tasks to be completed and prints each thread's name. How can I stop processing in 5 seconds?

Comment: Did you try `awaitTermination` followed by `shutdownNow`?

Comment: btw. futures also have a `cancel` method.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here as you mentioned is that your code is waiting for the tasks to complete before `shutdown()` can be called. Essentially this is because `CompletionService.take()` will block until a task completes. Furthermore, you need to keep track of the cumulated time taken to get the tasks results, since `CompletionService` won't do it for you.

The idea is to use instead `poll(long, TimeUnit)` and interpret a `null` result as a timeout expiration, after which you can immediately shutdown the executor service. This can be done for example like this:

```
try {
  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);     
  CompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executorService);
  // each callable sleeps randomly between 1-10 seconds and then prints the thread name
  List<Callable<String>> callables = createCallables();
  for (Callable<String> callable : callables) {
    completionService.submit(callable);
  }
  final long timeout = 5_000_000_000L; // 5 seconds in nanos
  long elapsed = 0L;
  int count = 0;
  final long start = System.nanoTime();
  // while not timed out and not all tasks have completed
  while (((elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start) < timeout) && (count < callables.size())) {
    // wait for at most the remaining time before timeout
    Future<String> result = completionService.poll(timeout - elapsed, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    if (result == null) {
      System.out.println("timed out after " + count + " tasks and " + ((System.nanoTime() - start)/1_000_000L) + " ms");
      break;
    }
    count++;
    System.out.println(result.get()); 
  }
  executorService.shutdownNow();
  System.out.println("done");
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I was able to test that it works with `createCallables()` implemented like this:

```
private static List<Callable<String>> createCallables() {
  Random rand = new Random(System.nanoTime());
  List<Callable<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    // between 1 and 10s
    final long time = 1000L * (1L + rand.nextInt(10));
    list.add(new Callable<String>() {
      @Override
      public String call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(time);
        return "ok after " + time + "s on thread " + Thread.currentThread();
      }
    });
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: I am looking for an easier way to do this than having myself to keep track of time elapsed

Comment: "Easy" comes with practice and experience, but good luck anyway.